# Warning with sscanf format

Tags: c, string, fgets, scanf

I've been getting the following warning when trying to write a program that only allows strings of numbers:

`warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[100]’`

Why am I getting this warning, and what does it mean/consequences? Not had any problems running the code.

The program:

```
char check[100];
char line[100];
int i;
int true = 0;
int main
{
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
sscanf(line, "%s" , &check);
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    if(isdigit(check[i]) == 0)
        {
        true++;
        }
    else
        continue;
    }

if(true>0)
    printf("Not a number.\n");
else
    printf("Is a number.\n");
return(0);
}
```

Comment: The title is misleading; the warning has nothing to do with `isdigit`.

Comment: Take the `&` out of `sscanf(lne, "%s", &check);`  Also, put some space between your lines of code, follow a style guide, etc.  And your `int main` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining about the use of `&check` in the following line.

```
sscanf(line, "%s" , &check);
```

The expected argument is just `check`.

```
sscanf(line, "%s" , check);
```

Comment: Ah, I never considered it could be the sscanf function. Thanks for your time.